# How should I split and pick up some id informations in a url with python

Tags: python, regex, url, python-requests

e.g:

```
base_url='127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/alert/zones/zz123/namespaces/12345nmspc'
```

I want to pick up the **namespaces' id** --- **'12345nmspc'**;

Do I have to use RE (and HOW?), or are there Pythonic ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), with a positive lookbehind for `namespaces/`:

```
import re
base_url='127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/alert/zones/zz123/namespaces/12345nmspc'

print(re.findall(r'(?<=namespaces/)[^/?]*', base_url))
```

Output:

```
['12345nmspc']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlparse` to successfully parse `base_url` and then have access to the path to finnally take what you want, something like

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> path = urlparse.urlparse(base_url).path
>>> segments = path.split('/')
>>> segments[-1]
'12345nmspc'
>>> segments[-2]
'namespaces'
>>>
```

Because `namespaces` is not at a fixed position you can use a simple regex to extract the `id` like below (assuming `namespaces` is always present):

```
>>> [namespaces_id] = re.findall(r'/namespaces/([^/]+)/?', path)
>>> namespaces_id
'12345nmspc'
>>>
```

Comment: Let's say ```namespaces``` place is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in functionality for this, [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). In this case, you could parse like this:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
base_url='127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/alert/zones/zz123/namespaces/12345nmspc'
namespace_id = re.search(r'namespaces/(.+)', urlparse(base_url).path).group(1)
```

This'll work pretty much no matter what, because it isolates the path and doesn't depend on the id's position being at a fixed place.

Comment: Thx, but actually, if ```base_url='127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/alert/zones/zz123/namespaces/12345nmspc/userid/001usr'```, this solution failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
base_url = "127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/alert/zones/zz123/namespaces/12345nmspc"
pattern = re.compile(r"\/namespaces\/((.)*)(\/)?")
match = re.search(pattern, base_url )
id = ""
if match.groups():
    id = match.groups()[0]
print(id)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25725050)